# Getting value from a collection on a certain property/key in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I have retrieved JSON from a file using the following snippet:

```
$thisJSON = (Get-Content $fullFilePath -Raw) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Now the json looks something like this:

```
{
   "Name" : "Fred",
   "Age" : 10
}
```

I wish to *loop* through this and get the key and the value. I thought this would work:

```
 Foreach($key in $myCollection){        
        $value = $myCollection[$key]
        Write-Host "Key : " $key
        Write-Host "Value : " $value 
    }
```

It seems to only loop once, when it should loop twice as the output I get is :

```
Key : @{Name=Fred; Age=10}
Value :
```

So the value can't be found, and the key returns the whole collection. I've searched online, I must be doing something incorrect.

My thinking was I may need to convert to object or something after reading it from file but Im not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to *iterate* over the properties, you can select all the keys (name) by accessing the `PsObject` property:

```
$thisJSON.PsObject.Properties |
     Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
     ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host "Key : " $_
        Write-Host "Value : " $thisJSON."$_"
     }
```

**Output:**

```
Key :  Name
Value :  Fred
Key :  Age
Value :  10
```

Comment: Perfect. Not sure why my example wasn't working, but yours works great and easily understood. Thank you